# How to Calculate Percentage of Revenue based on aggregate column Total sales?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, adventureworks

I am trying to add a column that calculate the Percentage of total revenue and I am stuck with the following error:

> Error:  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 Invalid column name
>   'Customerkey'.

In that line I’m trying to join Table 1 and Table 3 but MS SQL Server won’t recognize `T.Customerkey` even though customerkey exists in the `dbo.FactInternetSales` table. 
Also, when I add T.Grand_Tot_Rev in my Group By clause, it returns 0.04 for every row. I know it's wrong because I do not want `T.Grand_Tot_Rev` to be part of the aggregate, because it should remain constant for every record. How can I achieve that I am looking for? Thank you in advance. By the way, I am using the AdventureWorksDW2012 database.

```
SELECT fs.CustomerKey , 
       M.Total_sales , 
       M.Total_cost , 
       M.Total_sales - M.Total_cost AS Total_Margin , 
       T.Grand_Tot_Rev( M.Total_sales / T.Grand_Tot_Rev ) * 100 AS Prct_Total_Revenue
  FROM dbo.FactInternetSales fs , -- Table 1 --

( 
  SELECT customerkey , 
         SUM( SalesAmount )AS Total_Sales , 
         SUM( TotalProductCost )Total_cost
    FROM dbo.FactInternetSales
    GROUP BY customerkey 
) M , --Table 2 --

( 
  SELECT SUM( SalesAmount )AS Grand_Tot_Rev
    FROM dbo.FactInternetSales 
) T --Table 3 --

  WHERE fs.CustomerKey =  M.CustomerKey -- Join 1 --     
    AND M.CustomerKey = T.Customerkey   -- Join 2 -- 
  GROUP BY fs.CustomerKey , 
           M.Total_sales , 
           M.Total_cost , 
           T.Grand_Tot_Rev
  ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the T.Grand_Tot_Rev as a constant over all rows try removing the second join `AND M.CustomerKey = T.Customerkey   -- Join 2 --` so the query looks like this:

```
SELECT fs.CustomerKey , 
       M.Total_sales , 
       M.Total_cost , 
       M.Total_sales - M.Total_cost AS Total_Margin , 
       T.Grand_Tot_Rev,
      ( M.Total_sales / T.Grand_Tot_Rev ) * 100 AS Prct_Total_Revenue
  FROM dbo.FactInternetSales fs , -- Table 1 --

( 
  SELECT customerkey , 
         SUM( SalesAmount )AS Total_Sales , 
         SUM( TotalProductCost )Total_cost
    FROM dbo.FactInternetSales
    GROUP BY customerkey 
) M , --Table 2 --

( 
  SELECT SUM( SalesAmount )AS Grand_Tot_Rev
    FROM dbo.FactInternetSales
) T --Table 3 --

  WHERE fs.CustomerKey =  M.CustomerKey -- Join 1 --     
    --AND M.CustomerKey = T.Customerkey    -- Join 2 -- 
  GROUP BY fs.CustomerKey , 
           M.Total_sales , 
           M.Total_cost , 
           T.Grand_Tot_Rev
  ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Another way to write the same query that is a bit more compact and might have slightly better performance:

```
;WITH 
    T AS (
        SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) AS Grand_Tot_Rev  
        FROM dbo.FactInternetSales
    ),
    M AS (
       SELECT customerkey , 
        SUM(SalesAmount) AS Total_Sales , 
        SUM(TotalProductCost) AS Total_cost
       FROM dbo.FactInternetSales
       GROUP BY CustomerKey
)

SELECT 
    customerkey , 
    Total_Sales , 
    Total_cost,
    Total_Sales - Total_cost AS Total_Margin , 
    Grand_Tot_Rev,
    Total_Sales / Grand_Tot_Rev * 100 AS Prct_Total_Revenue   
FROM M, T
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

To see the really small values you can force a conversion to a wider data type:

```
;WITH 
    T AS (
        SELECT CAST(SUM(SalesAmount) AS decimal) AS Grand_Tot_Rev  
        FROM dbo.FactInternetSales
    ),
    M AS (
       SELECT customerkey , 
        CAST(SUM(SalesAmount) AS decimal(15,10)) AS Total_Sales , 
        CAST(SUM(TotalProductCost) AS decimal(15,10)) AS Total_cost
       FROM dbo.FactInternetSales
       GROUP BY CustomerKey
)

SELECT 
    customerkey , 
    Total_Sales , 
    Total_cost,
    Total_Sales - Total_cost AS Total_Margin , 
    Grand_Tot_Rev,
    Total_Sales / Grand_Tot_Rev * 100 AS Prct_Total_Revenue   
FROM M, T
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your suggestion does not work I had tried that before posting my questions. What happens is that the Prct_Total_revenue returns 0.04 for every record and that's not what I want. It should be different for every row. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Novice09 Are you sure it's wrong? When I run the query with the same DB I get back 18484 rows and the sum of the Prct_Total_Revenue comes out at 100%. I believe you might be mistaking a rounding error in the presentation with an actual error. Look at the last column in the http://pastebin.com/uANshfMr and you'll see that the percentage varies, but also that the individual contributions per customer is very small.

Comment: @Novice09 I added a version with casts, please try that.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, it had something to do with the decimal settings. The data type for sales amount and cost is "money" in the database. I adjusted the decimals and it worked. I am not really not familiar with the second way you rewrote the query starting with the "WITH" clause. There is no join with that method? One last question, how adjust the decimal for Prct_Tot_Revenue itself. I tried using the cast statement but I noticed that the calculated field Prct_Tot_Revenue is not the result of a sum. Is there a website where I can practice the analysis of adventure Works database?

Comment: There is a join, but I wrote it implicit as `FROM M, T` which is equivalent with `FROM M CROSS JOIN T`. You can control the formatting of the Prct_Tot_Revenue by surrounding it in a cast; look at this: http://pastebin.com/xm9TE0AL , the two queries are the same, only the first uses common table expressions (the WITH thing) whereas the other uses derived tables. I don't know if there is any website that has practice exercises for the AWDW database, but I know it's used in a lot on MS demos and stuff.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much. Learning a lot here!